How to remove grey background from UISearchBar inside UINavigationBar?
Normally, you can customize UISearchBar appearance, including the background color, using UIAppearance API. To customize the background color, you can use theme UISearchTextField, which is a UITextField subclass used in search bars:
UISearchTextField.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)


However, when UISearchBar is used in a UINavigationController, an additional background view is added with the tertiary system fill color; this will darken your search bar:

Inspecting the view hierarchy shows that this is an instance of _UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView. I’ve explored all the existing stack overflow questions on changing the search bar background color and could not find a solution that works with UIAppearance and accounts for this. Is there a way to hide or change the color of the view?

I was able to figure out a combination of UIAppearance styles that can make this work - but it requires an extension on UIView so you can re-apply the corner radius.
The first step is to set an empty image as the background image of the search bar field. This is sufficient to remove the extra background view:
UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)

However, this results in no corner radius being applied:

To style the corner radius using UIAppearance, add the following extension to UIView (or UISearchTextField to keep it more isolated):
private extension UIView {
    @objc dynamic var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get { layer.cornerRadius }
        set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
    }

    @objc dynamic var cornerCurve: CALayerCornerCurve {
        get { layer.cornerCurve }
        set { layer.cornerCurve = newValue }
    }
}

Then you can apply the default radius of 10, and a continuous curve, which will match the system:

Complete solution:
UISearchBar.appearance().setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .normal)
UISearchTextField.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
UISearchTextField.appearance().cornerRadius = 10
UISearchTextField.appearance().cornerCurve = .continuous


You should be cautious with using the .appearance(). This will alter the appearance for the entire app and not only on the page you are currently on. Unless you want that style everywhere you should write your own view or subclass UISeachBar.

Yes, of course! I should have mentioned this is for global theming in an app with UIKit and SwiftUI (where you can't use a custom subclass at all if you want to use the searchable modifier).
